# General question on Bounded linear operators and the constant involved

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

so the definition for a bounded linear operator $F:X \rightarrow Y$
is that 
$$||F(x)||_X \leq C||x||_Y$$ for some constant $C$ and all $x$. So my question: is the $C$ dependent on the choice of $x$?

For example I am thinking if $F(x_1,x_2) = (x_1,x_1+x_2)$ that is linear. Then $||F(x_1,x_2)|| = || (x_1,x_1+x_2)|| \leq ||(x_1,x_2)|| + ||(x_1,x_2)||$. Then because $C$ is independant of $x$ we cannot have $ ||(x_1,x_2)|| + ||(x_1,x_2)|| \leq C||(x_1,x_2)|| $, correct?
 Then this $F$ is not bounded.

Comment: $C$ must be a constant independent of $x$.

Comment: If $a\ne0$ then $F$ is not linear.

Comment: Fair $a$ has to be zero, I guess I made a bad example to illustrate my thoughts, maybe something like $F(x_1,x_2) = (x_1,x_1+x_2)$ that is linear. Then $||F(x_1,x_2)|| = || (x_1,x_1+x_2)|| \leq ||(x_1,x_2)|| + ||(x_1,x_2)||$. Then because $C$ is independant of $x$ we cannot have $ ||(x_1,x_2)|| + ||(x_1,x_2)|| \leq C||(x_1,x_2)|| $, correct? ( I will edit the question so it is reflective of what I wanted to say)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^2$, then 
\begin{align}
\|(x_1,x_1+x_2)\|&\leq \|(x_1,x_1)\|+\|(x_1,x_2)\|=|x_1|\,\|(1,1)\|+\|(x_1,x_2)\|\\ \ \\
&=\sqrt2\,|x_1|+\|(x_1,x_2)\|\\ \ \\
&\leq\sqrt2\,\|(x_1,x_2)\|+\|(x_1,x_2)\|\\ \ \\
&=(\sqrt2+1)\,\|(x_1,x_2)\|.
\end{align}
So you can take $C=\sqrt2+1$. The actual norm of $F$ is a bit smaller; it is not hard to check that $$\|F\|=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2.$$